# django's logout(request) also logout django admin and vise versa?

Tags: django, authentication

I'm using django's auth module to login and logout users in my website. But when I login a certain user to my website and go to django admin page, it also automatically logs in that user. Is this natural?

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def login_request(request):
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login(request, user)

def logout_request(request):
    logout(request)
```

EDIT:
I think this is the same as my question.
[logged-in-the app user is logged-out when superuser logs in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138450/logged-in-the-app-user-is-logged-out-when-superuser-logs-in-django-admin) Please confirm an answer

thanks

Comment: Yes its Natural behavior! what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because they use the same authentication backend.